# Magento 2 Configurable Related Products

Tags: magento2

How would I go about getting related products configurable options on the product page? I'd like customers to be able to directly add related products to cart without having to go the products page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up related products on product pages, you can configure this from the Edit Product page of a product in your inventory. There is "Related Products" tab, you add related products to the specific product from there. Then, on the product page a customer can see the related products and just click on "Add to Cart" button shown on each related product image.

Comment: I have this but I want the related products that are configurable to show their dropdown options on the page without having to go to that products page.